# Чтение записей из файла в отдельные списки

Tags: python, python-3.x, файловый-ввод-вывод

У меня в коде есть два таких списка:
Y = [20, 5, 10, 40, 15, 25]
X = [1,  2,  3, 8, 7, 4]

и одна переменная:
W = 10

Как реализовать заполнение данных из файла так, чтобы первая строка файла заполняла список Y, вторая - список X, а третья - W?

Comment: записать в переменные или из переменных в файл?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

если данные в `data.txt` файле такого вида:

```
20 5 10 40 15 25
1 2 3 8 7 4
10
```

прочитайте его, разделяя по переносу строки:

```
with open('data.txt') as f:
    lines = f.read().split('\n')
```

и заберите в переменные нужное вам:

```
x = [int(i) for i in lines[1].split()]
y = [int(i) for i in lines[0].split()]

w = int(lines[2])
```

в результате - списки интов в `x` и `y`, и инт в `w`:

```
>>> x
[1, 2, 3, 8, 7, 4]
>>> y
[20, 5, 10, 40, 15, 25]
>>> w
10
```